# Jenkins Stages Log/XML

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Where can I find the Jenkins Pipeline stages and its results stored. I am trying to find the logs/xml this image stored, I understand that we can find the system logs in var/logs/jenkins/jenkins.log however my requirement is to capture/find the jobs pipeline stages which might be in logs/xml in the server. If there are any plugins kindly suggest me on the same.

[Jenkins Pipeline Stages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ycccc.png)

Comment: click the build number and there will be a workspace link - that may show the files you seek. if you are using docker/kubernetes build agents, not all logs may be available

Comment: So you want to collect a separate log file per stage?

Comment: Thanks for the response @zett42. Yes, I need to record the build results and store it in an log or XML file. We need to analyse the results of each build and measure  the improvements to the developers.